# Remark on equality of cohomology groups (Milne, Remark 1.14)

Tags: group-cohomology

I'm having troubles with [Remark 1.14, page 69](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf) of these notes. Explicitly, if $$ 0 \to M \to J^0 \to J^1 \to \cdots $$ is an exact sequence of $ G $-modules, such that $ H^s(G, J^r) = 0$ for all $ s > 0 $ and all $ r $, then $ H^r(G, M) = H^r(J^{\bullet G}) $. I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious or if it's not that easy to show, since the author did not give any explanation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess that this follows from the fact that you can compute a derived functor using acyclic resolutions (see any book on homological algebra).

Comment: @Watson Thank you for your comment. Do you have any good introductory reference to recommend?

Comment: Proposition 54 [here](http://therisingsea.org/notes/DerivedFunctors.pdf) seems to be what you want. Here $T : A = k[G]$-$Mod \to Ab$ is the functor of invariants $M \mapsto M^G$.

Comment: @Watson Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard result in homological algebra as stated in the comments. The statement is as follows.

> Let $F: \mathscr A\to \mathscr B$ be a left exact functor between abelian categories with enough injectives. An object $X$ is $F$-acyclic if $R^iF(X)=0$ for $i>0$. If $X\to Y^*$ is a resolution of $X$ by $F$-acyclic objects, then $H^i(FY^*) = R^iF(X)$ for each $i$.

To prove this, one produces a double complex of injectives, which I will denote by $J^{i,j}$ ($i\geqslant -1, j\geqslant -1$), with (at least) the following properties.

1. For each fixed $i$, $J^i = J^{i,-1} \to J^{i,*}$ is an injective resolution ($i=-1$ gives the starting column for $X$), in particular $X$ is at position $(-1,-1)$.
2. For each $j$, the complex $J^{-1,j} \to J^{*,j}$ is an injective resolution.

The construction uses the Horseshoe lemma in a smart way, but otherwise is very elementary. The point is to consider it a sort of resolution (what is called a Cartan--Eilenberg resolution) of the complex $C^{*,-1}: M\to J^*$:

$$C^{*,-1} = J^{*,-1} \to J^{*,0}\to J^{*,1}\to J^{*,2}\to \cdots$$

For a more precise definition, you may consult Theorem 10.45 and the preceding discussion in Rotman's *Homological Algebra* (2nd edition). Ultimately one obtains the Grothendieck spectral sequence pursuing this idea and using the spectral sequence of a double complex.

In particular one has two maps of double complexes: one $\varepsilon$ from the injective resolution $J^{-1,*}$ to the remaining part $J_+$ of the complex (this diagram does not involve the coordinates with $i,j=-1$) given by the horizontal differential, and a map $\eta$ from $J^{*,-1}$ to $J_+$ given by the vertical one. Applying $F$, one gets the same diagrams but with $F$ about.

Now, since the $J^{i}$ are $F$-acyclic, this $F$-complex plus the row of $FJ^{*,-1}$ has acyclic columns, so its totalization is acyclic. Similarly, since injective objects are $F$-acyclic, this $F$-complex plus the column of $FJ^{-1,*}$ has acyclic rows, so its totalization is acyclic. Here we use the "Acyclic Assembly Lemma" of Weibel, which is a very simple version of the spectral sequence of a double complex.

Viewing the horizontal (resp. vertical) maps as morphisms $\varepsilon$ (resp $\varepsilon'$) of doble complexes, one notices that the cones of the maps $\operatorname{Tot}(F\varepsilon)$ and $\operatorname{Tot}(F\varepsilon')$ are both isomorphic to the totalization of the two augmented $F$-complexes, and since they are acyclic, both these maps are quasi-isomorphisms.

Now the domain of $\operatorname{Tot}(F\varepsilon)$ is just the complex that computes $R^iFM$, while the domain of $\operatorname{Tot}(F\varepsilon')$ is the complex that computes $H^i(FI^*)$, and both these complexes are quasi-isomorphic to $\operatorname{Tot}(FJ_+)$ through the maps above. This constructs the desired isomorphisms:

$$R^*FM \leftarrow H^*(\operatorname{Tot}(FJ_+))\rightarrow H^*(FI^*) $$